# RcppArmadillo: Lambda expression with each_slice

Tags: c++, r, lambda, rcpp, armadillo

I have a three dimensional array with positive definite matrices and I would like to obtain an array of the same size with the Cholesky factors of all matrices. I am using the Armadillo library and the `cube` type, for which there is the convenient function `each_slice` which I'm trying to use. But I am not getting the lambda expression to work correctly, so hopefully someone can help me and point out my mistake.

Here is a minimal example:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cube chol_array(arma::cube Sigma) {
  arma::cube Sigma_chol = Sigma;
  Sigma_chol.each_slice([](arma::mat X) {return arma::chol(X);});
  return Sigma_chol;
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cube chol_array2(arma::cube Sigma) {
  arma::cube Sigma_chol(size(Sigma));
  for (arma::uword i = 0; i < Sigma.n_slices; i++) {
    Sigma_chol.slice(i) = arma::chol(Sigma.slice(i));
  }
  return Sigma_chol;
}

/*** R
Sigma <- array(crossprod(matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3)), dim = c(3, 3, 2))
chol_array(Sigma)
chol_array2(Sigma)
*/
```

The function `chol_array2` does the job, but `chol_array` just returns the original matrices. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is the lack of references in the [`.each_slice()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_slice) call. Armadillo's use of lambda expressions require references to update the object and *not* a return statement.  In particular, we have:

> For form 3:
>
> apply the given lambda_function to each slice; **the function must accept a reference to a Mat object with the same element type as the underlying cube**

So, change:

```
Sigma_chol.each_slice([](arma::mat X) {return arma::chol(X);});
```

to:

```
Sigma_chol.each_slice([](arma::mat& X) {X = arma::chol(X);});
```

## Fixed Code

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// Enable lambda expressions.... 
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cube chol_array(arma::cube Sigma) {
  arma::cube Sigma_chol = Sigma;

  // NOTE: the '&' and saving _back_ into the object are crucial
  Sigma_chol.each_slice( [](arma::mat& X) { X = arma::chol(X); } ); 

  return Sigma_chol;
}
```

## Test code

```
set.seed(1113)
Sigma = array(crossprod(matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3)), dim = c(3, 3, 2))
all.equal(chol_array(Sigma), chol_array2(Sigma))
# [1] TRUE
```